# What is the minimum salary required for a Blue Card visa in Germany for a software developer (from India)

Tags: germany, immigration, indian-citizens, blue-card

**Question 1 :**

I have a prospective employer from Germany, Frankfurt who is ready to send me an employment offer letter anytime now. I live in India and I'm a software developer. What should be the minimum salary I should get to be able to apply for a Blue Card?

**Question 2 :**

My employer is unaware of any process needed to recruit from overseas. If my salary is lower than the EU Blue card norms, does he have to do any additional steps, like get FEA approval? What happens if my salary is at or above the Blue Card norms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum gross salary per year is 52,000 Euros. However, the minimum gross salary for jobs where there is a shortage of applicants is 40,560 Euros. Software Engineers belong to this category. You would need to get the letter from the employer, in this case, Beschäftigungs Stellenbeschreibung, that shows that the consent of the Federal Employment Agency can be provided.

In case your salary is above the norms, you just need to fill the application form(Antragaufenhaltstitel) and you don't need the consent from the Federal Employment Agency.

Comment: thank you for the answer. could you tell me what "Antragaufenhaltstitel" means? is it the set of documents I need to submit while applying for national work visa ?

Comment: My employer has not previously hired anyone outside Europe, so he has not filled up any forms like "Beschäftigungs Stellenbeschreibung". could you please guide me on what my employer has to file before I apply for a visa?

Comment: I can provide you with the documents, I have them on email. Antragaufenhaltstitel is your application form for the blue card and Stellenbeschreibung is the form that is filled by the employer giving details about your employement and your position.

Comment: "Antragaufenhaltstitel" and "Stellenbeschreibung" forms need to be filled only after I get my visa and arrive in Germany. Isn't that right? please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I have sent an email to you